# How to add add third party plugin in angular2

Tags: angular, plugins, datetimepicker

i am new to angularJS2, i want to add datetime picker in one of my forms. so i followed this [site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime-picker) for the creation of the datetime picker control. I ran this command

> npm install ng2-date-time-picker --save

and i am able to even import the file like this

```
import { DateTimePickerModule } from 'ng2-date-time-picker';
```

but when i run the appliaction, i get an error like this

[image]

This is the order, how i have linked the file in index.html

```
<base href="/">
    <title>Policy Intialization</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Polyfills for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

being an .net MVC developer, I am very confused on which path to follow to include a third party plugin. anyone help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

This is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BCD3cqv9u5I6BaXtafhW?p=info) for refrence

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime-picker

Comment: yes, and i have added the plunker, please refer that help me on this, thank you

Comment: Does your code work **before** adding the 3rd-party lib? What is this `boot.js` file? Who created that file and what is in it?

Comment: yes, if i comment the systemjs.config.js file which has the details of the datetime picker, it works properply, well the plunkr code doesnt have all the files because it has to be manually pasted, but the plunkr file can give you a brief idea about my projects main files